Condition of orthogonality of two solutions to a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients on a smooth chart
I try to solve Exercise $100$ on page 37 of this pdf

Let $\mathbf{r}:(u, v) \mapsto \mathbf{r}(u, v)$ be a smooth chart. Show that the solutions to the differential equation
$$
A \dot{u}^2+2 B \dot{u} \dot{v}+C \dot{v}^2=0,
$$
all meet orthogonally if and only if
$$
E C-2 F B+G A=0 .
$$

this is a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients. Does it always have two solutions?
If it has two solutions, solutions are curves on the chart $\mathbf{r}:(u, v) \mapsto \mathbf{r}(u, v)$, and the question is to prove the condition of orthogonality of the two curves.

Let $\tilde{u},\tilde{v}$ be the other solution of the differential equation.
Dividing by $\dot{v}^2$, I get $A(\frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}})^2+2 B \frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}}+C =0,$ so the two solutions of this quadratic equation satisfy Vieta's formulas
$$
\frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}}\frac{\dot{\tilde{u}}}{\dot{\tilde{v}}}=\frac{C}A
\\
\frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}}+\frac{\dot{\tilde{u}}}{\dot{\tilde{v}}}=-\frac{2B}A
$$
The two solutions are orthogonal on the chart iff
$$E \dot{u} \dot{\tilde{u}}+F(\dot{u} \dot{\tilde{v}}+\dot{\tilde{u}} \dot{v})+G \dot{v} \dot{\tilde{v}}=0
\\\iff E \frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}} \frac{\dot{\tilde{u}}}{\dot{\tilde{v}}}+F(\frac{\dot{u}}{\dot{v}}+\frac{\dot{\tilde{u}}}{\dot{\tilde{v}}})+G =0
\\\iff E \frac{C}A+F(-\frac{2B}A)+G =0
\\\iff E C-2 F B+G A=0 .
$$
